# typescript javascript library dependencies for production build

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm pretty new to web development and JavaScript. I'm currently working on a project where I'm using `plotly`. I found a typescript interface and included it in my typescript script like this:

```
import Plotly, { PlotlyHTMLElement } from "plotly.js-dist-min";
```

When I compile my typescript code to JavaScript the dependencies don't work anymore. currently I'm always editing my JavaScript output manually and correct the dependencies like this:

```
import Plotly, { PlotlyHTMLElement } from "plotly.js-dist-min"; //WORKS IN TS REMOVE IN JAVASCRIPT
import "../node_modules/plotly.js-dist-min/plotly.min.js"; //WORKS IN JS
import "./plotly.min.js"; //WORKS IN JS WHEN plotly.min.js is copied to dist folder
```

Is it possible to automatize the manual steps whenever I call "tsc -p ."

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "ES2017",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

I guess that's a very basic question but I couldn't find a way yet.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the import. Can you edit your post and add your TypeScript config?

Comment: sure, that's the config file i'm currently using:

`{  
    "compilerOptions": {  
      "target": "ESNext",  
      "module": "esnext",  
      "lib": ["ES2017", "DOM"],  
      "outDir": "./dist",  
      "rootDir": "./src",  
      "strict": true,  
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false,  
      "esModuleInterop": true,  
      "skipLibCheck": true,  
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  
    }  
  }  `